# How to use appropriate regex to find a pattern in awk?

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, regular-expression

Using the following example, I am trying to figure it out the `regex` which cover the following pattern in my `awk program`.

- The output could be only numbers no more than 5 length : *i.g.* 15251
- The output could have two letters only `"H" & "O"` and any numbers before `=< 3` and after `=<` 5 and "O" could be optional: *i.g* HO722  or
  799H89090
- The output could **NOT** include anything that has space  or any words except digits :*i.g* hkks kjsla aaa --> not acceptable

  cat filename

  ```
  00ISM00123
  189902
  078HP890201
  HO90902
  123H7292
  234HO7027
  12345556
  GV18029039
  kslal HOsjlk jj 123
  687iOu7900
  ```

I tried the following script

```
 awk  '$1~/^[0-9]{,3}([hH][oO]?)[^a-zA-Z]/' filename`
```

but dose not cover the digits in filename  *i.e.*

```
>     189902 
>     12345556
```

when I tried the following script still the output is not correct as expected!

```
awk  '$1~/^([0-9]{,3}([hH][oO]?)?)[^a-zA-Z]/' filename
```

any help with explanation is highly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I split this up into two regexes, this looks like it is working :

```
cat filename | grep -E '^[0-9]{5}$|^[0-9]{0,3}[hH]{1}[oO]{0,1}[0-9]{0,5}$'
```

The first part of the regex will try the filenames having only 5 digits, and the second part is trying for filenames having 0-3 digits, 1 'h' or 'H' letter, 0 or 1 'oO' letter, 0 to 5 digits.

This regex works with `awk` too :

```
cat filename | awk  '/^[0-9]{5}$|^[0-9]{0,3}[hH]{1}[oO]{0,1}[0-9]{0,5}$/ {print}'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not completely tied to awk, `grep` works well here:

```
$ grep -E '\<[[:digit:]]{1,3}HO?[[:digit:]]{1,5}\>' filename
123H7292
234HO7027
```

Is that the output you're looking for? I wonder if `HO90902` should match.

The `\<` and `\>` are word boundaries, so "12345678H123" will not match.